# Feature-wise Normalization of Predictor Variables in R

Tags: r

So I want to fit a neural network later to predict the continous numeric variable Outstate in the College dataset from the ISLR packagage as a function of the 17 other (predictor) variables in the dataset. Before I fit the neural network I need to do feature-wise normalization of only the predictor variables. Since there are 17 predictors I don't want to have to explicitly type out every variable I wanna standardize. Is there any feasible way of doing this in R? The scale function scales all variables in the dataset from what I understand.

```
library(ISLR)

set.seed(1)
College$Private = as.numeric(College$Private)
train.ind = sample(1:nrow(College),0.5*nrow(College))
college.train = College[train.ind,]
college.test = College[-train.ind,]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will standardise each feature with base R scale() which centres data based on the columns means and then divides by the standard deviations i.e. Z-score standardisation.

```
preds = colnames(college.test)[-9]

college.test[,preds] = lapply(college.test[,preds], scale)
```

Comment: In your example, would it not work to simply use the base R scale() function instead of using my own if I wanna do Z score standardization?

Comment: Yes you are right and I have updated my answer. I misread part of your question.